# mysql how to select multiple values by email or unique value in column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to **select firsname, mobileno, city,employee-name ect.. by email or by unique code**, because email will differ user by user and the thing I'm using Email as login, so if any user input an **email or Code** I want to Echo him/his details.

Consider My database Has:

```
id       firstname    MobileNo     City     State        Email      Code         
1          xxxxx      0000000    Arkansas  California  YYY@xx.com   ABCDE
```

So I'm uses the query but it doesn't work

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname,Mobileno,City,Employee-Name FROM `clients` WHERE email = '$email'  AND code = '$code'");
```

So Please Help Me Out, Thanks In Advance.

Comment: use OR instead of AND

Comment: You answer your own question "by email or by unique code". Just use `OR` instead of `AND` in your `WHERE` condition, so if one of it it's true, the query will return the info about that user.

And don't use mysql, its deprecated! Use mysqli or PDO and take care of sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title says it all. Use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname,Mobileno,City,Employee-Name 
                    FROM `clients` 
                    WHERE email = '$email'  
                       OR code = '$code'")
```

`OR` means either `email='$email'` or `code='$code'`.

If you use `AND` both conditions should be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

as i know you want use one of email or code?

i think you should use this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname,Mobileno,City,Employee-Name FROM `clients` WHERE email = '$email'  OR code = '$code'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with `OR` condition.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT firstname,Mobileno,City,Employee-Name 
                    FROM `clients` 
                    WHERE email = '.$email.'  
                       OR code = '.$code.'")
```